# Error deploying Xamarin to Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am getting started with Xamarin and am trying to run the example project. I've managed to install the Android SDK and have created a virtual device to test with. However, when I try to run the project, I get a non-descriptive error that indicates that I should check the log file. When I do, I find the following two stack traces:

> System.InvalidOperationException    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.StartEmulator(IAndroidVirtualDevice
>   virtualDevice, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.cs:line
>   148    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.StartUp(IMonoAndroidDevice
>   device, IProgressReport progress, IAndroidVirtualDeviceProvider
>   virtualDeviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line
>   0    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.Execute(StartupVirtualDeviceCommand
>   command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line
>   45    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand
>   command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line
>   125    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
>   in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line
>   118    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() System.InvalidOperationException
>   at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase.ProcessAggregateInnerException(Exception
>   innerException, IProgressReport progress) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line
>   37    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand
>   command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line
>   145    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1_0.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;b__0()
>   in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3345\2e397405\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line
>   118    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Does anyone have any clue what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was that my computer didn't have hardware virtualization turned on. I never found any kind of output that told me so, but when I turned it on it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got issues using the built-in emulator. I'd recommand you to try debugging with a real device or using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) to create emulators. It requires Virtual Box to run, but is really useful, as there is a lot of devices that can be simulated, so you can test your apps on several APIs and screen sizes.