# Can't start Android Virtual Device with Xamarin and Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I just installed Xamarin for VS2015, and have created a blank Android app. Unfortunately, neither of the Android Virtual Devices provided by Xamarin will run the little template app I was provided. Visual Studio gives an unhelpful message of "There were deployment errors". Looking into the logs reveals this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.StartEmulator(IAndroidVirtualDevice virtualDevice, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.cs:line 148
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.StartUp(IMonoAndroidDevice device, IProgressReport progress, IAndroidVirtualDeviceProvider virtualDeviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 72
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.Execute(StartupVirtualDeviceCommand command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 45
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 152
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 118
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProgressReport Error: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:31:19.0670] System.InvalidOperationException
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase.ProcessAggregateInnerException(Exception innerException, IProgressReport progress) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 38
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 145
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 118
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProgressReport Error: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:32:08.4234] System.InvalidOperationException
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.StartEmulator(IAndroidVirtualDevice virtualDevice, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.cs:line 148
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.StartUp(IMonoAndroidDevice device, IProgressReport progress, IAndroidVirtualDeviceProvider virtualDeviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 72
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.Execute(StartupVirtualDeviceCommand command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 45
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 132
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProgressReport Error: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:32:08.4404] System.InvalidOperationException
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase.ProcessAggregateInnerException(Exception innerException, IProgressReport progress) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 38
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 145
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 118
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidDeviceSettings Information: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:32:38.9678] Settings successfully saved.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidDeviceSettings Information: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:36:56.2277] Settings successfully saved.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProgressReport Error: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:37:04.7492] System.InvalidOperationException
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.StartEmulator(IAndroidVirtualDevice virtualDevice, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.cs:line 148
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.StartUp(IMonoAndroidDevice device, IProgressReport progress, IAndroidVirtualDeviceProvider virtualDeviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 72
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.Execute(StartupVirtualDeviceCommand command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 45
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 152
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 118
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProgressReport Error: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:37:04.7662] System.InvalidOperationException
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase.ProcessAggregateInnerException(Exception innerException, IProgressReport progress) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 38
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 145
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\ee3cfcdd\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 118
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidDeviceSettings Information: 0 : [2016-07-09 15:41:33.7269] Settings successfully saved.
```

Googling the error brings up [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967227/error-deploying-xamarin-to-android), which was solved by enabling hardware virtualization, but I'm not quite sure what that means. I've tried to troubleshoot myself, but I have no idea what's even going on. Making matters worse, there seem to be two separate copies of the Android SDK on my computer, one in `%USER_HOME%/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk` and one in `%USER_HOME%/AppData/Local/Xamarin/MonoForAndroid/AndroidSDK`. The one in `Android` has the SDK Manager and AVD Manager in it, but Xamarin's doesn't. As far as I can tell, nothing seems to use the one in `Android`, but it was installed by Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is embarrassing. I was using the AVD manager in `%USER_HOME%/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk`. When I open the one in `Xamarin` in Visual Studio, it works perfectly on the first time.

Comment: Though you found the solution to your problem, as ThamiDev said in an answer, you really should take a look at Genymotion, it really is a good piece of sofware, fast to boot, with a lot of different devices to use !

Comment: While Genymotion is faster, its locked some features behind a paywall, most notably networking, and I can't justify the expense.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Genymotion emulator...it will clarify if the problem is with the Virtualisation or the emulator itself.
visit https://www.genymotion.com/